# don't work reload data CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have a collection in the `ViewController1`, if i click that it goes to `ViewController2` where i can change a image; when i push back button on the navigation controller to go back in the ViewController1 i should see the image i changed in the `ViewController2`. My problem is that i need to reload the data of the CollectionView but i can't do it! I already tried to put `CollectionView.reloaddata()` in the `**ViewWillAppear**`, but nothing happened! How can i do this?

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell2"

class CollectionViewControllerStatiVegetarian: UICollectionViewController {

    let baza1 = Baza()

    @IBOutlet var CollectionViewOut: UICollectionView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        CollectionViewOut.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        let backround = CAGradientLayer().turquoiseColor()
        backround.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.collectionView?.backgroundView = UIView()
        self.collectionView?.backgroundView?.layer.insertSublayer(backround, at: 0) 
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        let size2 = baza1.superTuples(name: "2")
        let x = Mirror(reflecting: size2).children.count  // 
        return Int(x+1)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell_VegetarianStaty
        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            cell.shapka_stati_vegetarian.image = nil
            let superTupl = baza1.superTuplesShapka(Nomer_tupl: (indexPath.row-1))
            cell.label.text = superTupl.5
            let tupl = baza1.superTuplesShapka(Nomer_tupl: (indexPath.row-1))
                if (tupl.2 == 1) {
                    cell.shapka_stati_vegetarian.image = nil
                    cell.shapka_stati_vegetarian.image = UIImage(named: "fon_galochka.png")
                } else {}
        } else {
            cell.shapka_stati_vegetarian.image = UIImage(named: "shapkastaty")
            cell.label.text = ""
        }
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize  {

        let screenWidth  = UIScreen.main.fixedCoordinateSpace.bounds.width
        let height = screenWidth*550/900+20
        var size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: 73)
        if indexPath.row==0 {
            size = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: height)
        }
        return size
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row != 0 {
            numb_cell = indexPath.row
            let bazaSh = Baza()
            let f = bazaSh.superTuplesShapka(Nomer_tupl: (indexPath.row-1) )
            let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewStaty")  as! ViewController
            vc.obr = f.3
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add code from `ViewController2` where you change data for `UICollectionView`

Comment: If you already use an array of objects as datasource you do not need a delegate. Pass the object to vc2 (for reference) change the image and when it comes back, reload it in viewwillappear.

Answer (score 1):

Views are loaded only once in the lifetime of a view controller, so `viewDidLoad` is only run once.

One way to do this is to reload the data in `viewWillAppear` which is fired when the view appears, but this might run many times.

Another way is to have a delegate method of vc2 that is implemented by vc1. This delegate method is run when the data is changed in vc2 and since vc1 implements the delegate, it can then choose to reload the view.

Yet another way, and one that I prefer, is to use something like Core Data as a model. That way when vc2 changes the data, vc1 can be observing the state of objects it is interested in and react to changes in the model through the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods.

You could choose to use Realm as a persistence mechanism, and I'm sure there is a similar way to observe the model and react to changes.

Answer (score 0):

inn order to reloadData in background thread, you need to use

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { self.collectionView.reloadData() }
```

Answer (score 0):

implement your vc from

```
UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource
```

then in 
viewDidLoad()

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
```